# How to use a variable outside of a function in google maps sdk

Tags: swift, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have the following structure

```
struct Talleres : Codable {
    let id : Int?
    let title : String?
}
```

I use to extract the data of a json and to add markers in google maps (SDK).

With the variable `marker.accessibilityLabel = state.title` I save the title to use it in another function.

```
func jsonMapTaller() {
.
.
.
    for state in self.marcadores {
        let coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: long)
        let marker = GMSMarker(position: coordinates)
        marker.map = self.map
        marker.icon = UIImage(named: "pin")
        marker.accessibilityLabel = state.title
    }
}
```

Using the data stored in `marker.accessibilityLabel` I add this information (title) to a custom InfoWindows in the following function:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
.
.
.
    let myTitle:String! = marker.accessibilityLabel!
    infoWindow.titleLbl.text = myTitle
.
.
.
    infoWindow.center = mapView.projection.point(for: location)
    infoWindow.center.y = infoWindow.center.y - 107
    infoWindow.infoBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(infoWindow)
    return false
}
```

**How do I save more variables**? For example, `state.id` and be able to use it in the function `func mapView (_mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store data and then use it in another function, use `userData`

```
for state in self.marcadores {
        let coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: long)
        let marker = GMSMarker(position: coordinates)
        marker.map = self.map
        marker.icon = UIImage(named: "pin")
        marker.accessibilityLabel = state.title

       // store current marker data
        marker.userData = state
    }
```

Then you can invoke the data in another function like this:(example for id):

```
 myID = (marker.userData as! Talleres).id
 print(myID)
```